# How get Index and length of inserted | deleted string in textArea with Jscript|JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, addeventlistener

If string inserted or deleted from textarea (Event). Is there is a method or propriety to get start and end of that change?

one solution I know.

1. store current string
2. addEventListener('change', dosomething);
3. compare both strings in 1 and 2.
4. return start and end

Is there any defined method for that approach?

Comment: What do you mean by _"get start and end of that change"_ ?

Comment: case1 textarea contain "Rayon" . case2 user inserted "khwarizm" at index 2 textarea content became "Rakhwarizmyon" start = 2, end = 9

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming :

"Comparing Start/End of that change" means:comparing before/after a keypress event(for e.g.backspace/alphanumeric chars).

The solution would be to:

1.Have 2 strings (for e.g.)**str1**(before), **str2**(after).

2.Give the initial value of the textarea to **str1**.

3.Attach a keypress event handler to that textarea.

4.So, when the keypress occurs,store the current value of the textarea in str2.
Now do String comparison between **str1** and **str2** and you will have the result.

5.After this comparison,give the value of **str2** to **str1**(Since the **after** will become the **before** for the next comparison).

Hope this helps :)